# Highchart Activity Gauge always display text in the center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I want to use Highchart's activity gauge as some kind of circle animation surrounding a number/ figure in text form. The default behaviour is the text in the center of the chart will be displayed only if the user hovered over the series.

There is an existing solution by Mustapha here: http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/ubb2wz72/

```
$(function () {

// Uncomment to style it like Apple Watch
/*
if (!Highcharts.theme) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'black'
        },
        colors: ['#F62366', '#9DFF02', '#0CCDD6'],
        title: {
            style: {
                color: 'silver'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
                color: 'silver'
            }
        }
    });
}
// */

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        marginTop: 50
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Activity',
        style: {
            fontSize: '24px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
        positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
            return {
                x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                y: 180
            };
        }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [{ // Track for Move
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Exercise
            outerRadius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }, { // Track for Stand
            outerRadius: '62%',
            innerRadius: '38%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            borderWidth: '34px',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Move',
        borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            radius: '100%',
            innerRadius: '100%',
            y: 80
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Exercise',
        borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            radius: '75%',
            innerRadius: '75%',
            y: 65
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Stand',
        borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
            radius: '50%',
            innerRadius: '50%',
            y: 50
        }]
    }]
},

/**
 * In the chart load callback, add icons on top of the circular shapes
 */
function callback() {

    // Move icon
    this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8])
        .attr({
            'stroke': '#303030',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'zIndex': 10
        })
        .translate(190, 26)
        .add(this.series[2].group);

    // Exercise icon
    this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8, 'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8])
        .attr({
            'stroke': '#303030',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'zIndex': 10
        })
        .translate(190, 61)
        .add(this.series[2].group);

    // Stand icon
    this.renderer.path(['M', 0, 8, 'L', 0, -8, 'M', -8, 0, 'L', 0, -8, 8, 0])
        .attr({
            'stroke': '#303030',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'zIndex': 10
        })
        .translate(190, 96)
        .add(this.series[2].group);
});

var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
chart.tooltip.hide = function () {};
});
```

But the problem is if I remove 2 out of the 3 default series (leaving only 1), this solution does not work anymore. This is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v21zefzs/

```
$(function () {

// Uncomment to style it like Apple Watch
/*
if (!Highcharts.theme) {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'black'
        },
        colors: ['#F62366', '#9DFF02', '#0CCDD6'],
        title: {
            style: {
                color: 'silver'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            style: {
                color: 'silver'
            }
        }
    });
}
// */

Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        marginTop: 50
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Activity',
        style: {
            fontSize: '24px'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px'
        },
        pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}%</span>',
        positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
            return {
                x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                y: 180
            };
        }
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [{ // Track for Exercise
            outerRadius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]).setOpacity(0.3).get(),
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            borderWidth: '34px',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Exercise',
        borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
        data: [{
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            radius: '75%',
            innerRadius: '75%',
            y: 65
        }]
    }]
},

/**
 * In the chart load callback, add icons on top of the circular shapes
 */
function callback() {

    // Exercise icon
    this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8, 'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8])
        .attr({
            'stroke': '#303030',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'zIndex': 10
        })
        .translate(190, 61)
        .add(this.series[2].group);

});

var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
point.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
chart.tooltip.refresh(point); // Show the tooltip
chart.tooltip.hide = function () {};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error in the console. You should fix the code responsible for rendering arrows.

```
   this.renderer.path(['M', -8, 0, 'L', 8, 0, 'M', 0, -8, 'L', 8, 0, 0, 8, 'M', 8, -8, 'L', 16, 0, 8, 8])
        .attr({
            'stroke': '#303030',
            'stroke-linecap': 'round',
            'stroke-linejoin': 'round',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            'zIndex': 10
        })
        .translate(190, 61)
        .add(this.series[0].group); //it tried add path to a non-existing 3rd series
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/v21zefzs/1/

Comment: damn how could I missed this. Thank You!